# How to Set Up Facades in Laravel 5.2 (outside of /app)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm asking/answering because I have had so much trouble getting this working and I'd like to show a **step-by-step** implementation.

References:

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/facades#creating-facades
- http://www.n0impossible.com/article/how-to-create-facade-on-laravel-51

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This may not be the *only* way to implement facades in Laravel 5, but here is **how I did it**.

We're going to create a custom `Foo` facade available in the `Foobar` namespace.

## 1. Create a custom class

First, for this example, I will be creating a new folder in my project. It will get its own [namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php) that will make it easier to find.

In my case the directory is called **Foobar**:

[image]

In here, we'll create a new PHP file with our class definition. In my case, I called it `Foo.php`.

```
<?php
// %LARAVEL_ROOT%/Foobar/Foo.php

namespace Foobar;


class Foo
{
    public function Bar()
    {
        return 'got it!';
    }
}
```

## 2. Create a facade class

In our fancy new folder, we can add a new PHP file for our facade. I'm going to call it `FooFacade.php`, and I'm putting it in a different namespace called **Foobar\Facades**. *Keep in mind that the namespace in this case does not reflect the folder structure!*

```
<?php
// %LARAVEL_ROO%/Foobar/FooFacade.php

namespace Foobar\Facades;


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Foo extends Facade
{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'foo'; // Keep this in mind
    }
}
```

- Bear in mind what you return in `getFacadeAccessor` as you will need that in a moment.

Also note that you are extending the existing [Facade](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.html) class here.

## 3. Create a new provider using `php artisan`

So now we need ourselves a fancy new provider. Thankfully we have the awesome `artisan` tool. In my case, I'm gonna call it `FooProvider`.

```
php artisan make:provider FooProvider
```

**Bam!** We've got a provider. [Read more about service providers here.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/providers) For now just know that it has two functions (`boot` and `register`) and we will add some code to `register`. We're going to [bind](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/container#binding) our new provider our app:

```
$this->app->bind('foo', function () {
    return new Foo; //Add the proper namespace at the top
});
```

So this **`bind('foo'`** portion is actually going to match up with what you put in your `FooFacade.php` code. Where I said `return 'foo';` before, I want this bind to match that. (If I'd have said `return 'wtv';` I'd say `bind('wtv',` here.)

Furthermore, we need to tell Laravel where to find `Foo`!

So at the top we add the namespace

```
use \Foobar\Foo;
```

Check out the whole file now:

```
<?php
// %LARAVEL_ROOT%/app/Providers/FooProvider.php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Foobar\Foo;

class FooProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('foo', function () {
            return new Foo;
        });
    }
}
```

- Make sure you use **`Foobar\Foo`** and not `Foobar\Facades\Foo` - your IDE might suggest the wrong completion.

## 4. Add our references to `config/app.php`

Now we have to tell Laravel we're interested in using these random files we just created, and we can do that in our `config/app.php` file.

1. Add your provider class reference to [`'providers'`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/app.php#L124): `App\Providers\FooProvider::class`
2. Add your facade class reference to [`'aliases'`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/app.php#L172): `'Foo' => Foobar\Facades\Foo::class`

*Remember, in **aliases**, where I wrote `'Foo'`, you will want to put the name you want to reference your facade with there. So if you want to use `MyBigOlFacade::helloWorld()` around your app, you'd start that line with `'MyBigOlFacade' => MyApp\WhereEverMyFacadesAre\MyBigOlFacade::class`*

## 5. Update your `composer.json`

The last code change you should need is to update your `composer.json`'s [`psr-4`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4) spaces. You will have to add this:

```
    "psr-4": {
        "Foobar\\" : "Foobar/",
        // Whatever you had already can stay
    }
```

## Final move

Okay so now that you have all that changed, the last thing you need is to refresh the caches in both composer and artisan. Try this:

```
composer dumpautoload
php artisan cache:clear
```

## Usage & A Quick Test:

Create a route in `app/routes.php`:

```
Route::get('/foobar', 'FooBarController@testFoo');
```

Then run

```
php artisan make:controller FooBarController
```

And add some code so it now looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Foobar\Facades\Foo;

use App\Http\Requests;

class FooBarController extends Controller
{
    public function testFoo()
    {
        dd(Foo::Bar());
    }
}
```

You should end up with the following string:

[image]

---

## Troubleshooting

- **If you end up with and error saying it cannot find the class `Foobar\Facades\Foo`,** try running `php artisan optimize`

Comment: **Please!** If you use this guide and something does not work - let me know so I can fix it!

Comment: Another thing, I omitted the cache clear and Laravel returned me a "Class not found error", so I ran the command **php artisan optimize** and everything worked

Comment: Thanks @IlGala, I've made some edits including a pointer about using the `artisan optimize` command

Comment: What is use `Foobar\Join;`? And unfortunately all I get as the end result is `Class 'Foobar\Facades\Foo' not found`. Followed the directions down the the letter.

Comment: I had changed the names of my classes before putting them on SO. I guess I forgot to change that class name! It should read `Foobar\Foo`, I think.