# Override laravel Mailgun Transport for support multiple domain (Laravel 5.2)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, mailgun

We are sending email from our application by mailgun. We are using laravel 5.2.

But we have multiple mailgun domain created to sending email.

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
    'business_domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN_FOR_BUSINESS'),
    'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET')
],
```

Now we wants to send email like this.

1. **Mail::send()** this methods sending email by default domain.
2. But when we wants to create a different facade like
   **MailByBusiness::send()** with send email by business domain.

for archiving this functionality, how to override mailgun transport class and make a facade ?

Comment: This question is very broad for SO, and it is likely to be closed unless you edit it and narrow it down to a specific problem you are having - eg show us what you tried, and where you got stuck.  There are plenty of answers here about how to set mail config dynamically, eg https://stackoverflow.com/q/45146260/6089612, https://stackoverflow.com/q/23438342/6089612, https://stackoverflow.com/q/45327955/6089612 ...

Comment: And there are also many answers about how to create a facade, eg: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35639737/6089612, https://stackoverflow.com/q/50758512/6089612, https://stackoverflow.com/q/38972626/6089612 ... What have you tried?